# why RelativeLayout.BELOW doesn't work?

Tags: android, scale, android-relativelayout

Please, help me. I have custom ImageView in RelativeLayout. The ImageView takes only part of the screen. I use .setImageBitmap(input) to set image and can drag the ImageView. 
When i use setScaleX and setScaleY to have image biger then screen, my image climbs onto other views (updateButton and other ImageView) . How can I set it below other views.

Custom ImageView params:

```html
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
this.setScaleX(2);
this.setScaleY(2);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.updateButton);
params.bottomMargin = updateButton.getLayoutParams().width*2;
```

On the bottom of the screen I have button and TextView. I want ImageView doesnt climb onto them. Why params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,) doesn't work?

My .xml:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.eleizo.firstapplication.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/topRL">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/updateButton"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button_refresh_icon_72"
        android:background="@null" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: there is no solution for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addRule` like this,

```
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
this.setScaleX(2);
this.setScaleY(2);
//params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, [id of the view below]);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.updateButton);
setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Please see I edit my question.

Comment: updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
this.setScaleX(1);
this.setScaleY(1);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, [id of the view below]);
layout.addView(tv1, params1);
```